# Google Voice Recognition on Movies

Tags: voice-recognition, sox

I've had excellent results with the [Google API for speech recognition](https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1730160) with natural dialogues, however for sounds from Youtube videos or movies recognition is poor or nonexistent.

Recording sounds on an iPhone 4 of my voice in both Spanish to English is recognized, but with the same phone at a movie is almost impossible, even a scene with a character talking with little background noise. Only once had success.

I try to clean up the sound with [SoX (Sound eXchange)](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) using noisered and compand efects, without any success.

Any idea? Or simply are sounds that can not be identified by the Google API for more you change? It will have better success with other speech recognition software?

Answer (score 0):

Google voice recognizer (and most other recognizers) is not compatible with [reverberation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverberation) effects. In most video scenes distance between person and microphone more than 1-3 meter. Try to put your phone on table and recognize smth from 3 meters distance. This will does not lead to anything but sound quality will be very good.